# C++:initializing argument 1 of ‘int Agent::tun_alloc(char*, int)’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I have a class, which is

```
    class Agent{

    private:
       ....
       ....
       int tun_alloc(char *dev, int flags);

    public:
       ....
       ....
    }



    int Agent::tun_alloc(char *dev, const int flags) {

      struct ifreq ifr;
      int fd, err;
      char clonedev[] = "/dev/net/tun";

      if( (fd = open(clonedev , O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
        perror("Opening /dev/net/tun");
        exit(1);
      }

      memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

      ifr.ifr_flags = flags;

      if (*dev) {
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
      }

      if( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)) < 0 ) {
        perror("ioctl(TUNSETIFF)");
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
      }

      strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);

      return fd;
    }
```

I always get error `initializing argument 1 of ‘int Agent::tun_alloc(char*, int)’ [-fpermissive]` for `int tun_alloc(char *dev, int flags);` when I build project on eclipse, what are potential problems?

if I add a `const`

```
     int tun_alloc(const char *dev, int flags);
```

then there is no error, but I need to change the content of dev.

Comment: do you have a `#define dev` somewhere in your code?  You'll really need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as there is nothing wrong with what you pasted so far (assuming `....` stands for valid code).

Comment: This is incorrect use of `strncpy`; you should either do a length check followed by `strcpy`, or use `snprintf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided full error and the code how you actually call your function, but you might get such error when you provide `const char*` to a `char*` argument, ie:

```
std::string s;
tun_alloc(s.c_str(),0);
```

`c_str()` returns `const char*`, so you want:

```
int tun_alloc(const char *dev, int flags);
              ^^^^^ ~~~ !!
```

[edit]

> but I need to change the content of dev.

After seeing full source code,  I would replace char *dev with std::string& dev. Now you will be able to pass string to function and also return string from function. IF you want to stay with char* then you would have to pass lenght of dev to tun_alloc and return error with correct length in case ITS too short.

Comment: This suggestion needs modification because `tun_alloc` expects to receive a null-terminated string

Comment: Also the `tun_alloc` function writes out to `dev` and it's unclear if it might try to write a longer string...